# Java ListChangeListener WasUpdated() doesn't work

Tags: java, javafx

I want to trigger some code when a object called EventShowable have been modified in an observableList.
Here is my code.

```
                mainApp.getCalendars().get(i).getListEvents().addListener(new ListChangeListener<EventShowable>() {
                @Override
                public void onChanged(ListChangeListener.Change<? extends EventShowable> c) {
                    while (c.next()) {
                        if (c.wasUpdated()) {
                          //this doesn't work.
                          //perform updated

                        }
                        if (c.wasAdded()){
                            //perform something }
```

The wasAdded() perform well but not the wasUpdate().
How to get something that works when a EventShowable have been modified ? Thanks

P.S : in the JavaDoc : 
public boolean wasUpdated()
Indicates that the elements between getFrom() (inclusive) to getTo() exclusive has changed. **This is the only optional event type and may not be fired by all ObservableLists.**
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/ListChangeListener.Change.html#wasUpdated--

Answer (score 2):

Create your list using an [`extractor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/FXCollections.html#observableArrayList-javafx.util.Callback-).

You haven't really given enough detail to give a complete answer, but if your `EventShowable` defines properties such as

```
public class EventShowable {
    public IntegerProperty xProperty() { ... }
    public StringProperty yProperty() { ... }
    // ...
}
```

then to create a list that fires update events when `x` or `y` change you do

```
ObservableList<EventShowable> listEvents = 
    FXCollections.observableArrayList(eventShowable ->
        new Observable[] { eventShowable.xProperty(), eventShowable.yProperty() });
```

Comment: Thanks , my EventShowable containts only properties. But where do i have to put the code of the ObservableList<EventShowable> listEvents=... ? in my EventShowable class or in my code near c.wasAdded()? I don't understand what this piece of code do.