# ListView setCellFactory messes up binding unless anonymous-inner-class?

Tags: java, listview, javafx, custom-cell, anonymous-inner-class

Why do I require to anonymously subclass a JavaFX Callback instance when passing it to `ListView::setCellFactory` for a binding with the `selectedItemProperty` (of `ListView::getSelectionModel`) to work in the sense of actually getting notified when the `selectedItemProperty` changes?

Okay so i've cloned james-d's nested controller example: https://github.com/james-d/Nested-Controller-Example

And i'm wondering why the binding with the editor still works when replacing `MainController.java`'s `personList.setCellFactory` line with this minimal code (where the cells are blank but the binding with the editor still works)

```
personList.setCellFactory(param -> new ListCell<Person>(){});
```

But if i remove the `{}` the textfields are not updated anymore when selecting those 'blank' cells

```
personList.setCellFactory(param -> new ListCell<Person>());
```

I have figured that this same problem persists when using a custom `ListCellFactory` (where each `ListCell`'s `textProperty` is bound and displaying properly), so the problem does not lie in the implementation itself (sort of), but rather in how the callback parameter passed to setCellFactory is instantiated, wich apparently must be an anonymous subclass for the binding with the selectedItemProperty to work as expected (and who know what else might be affected).

*DOES NOT WORK*:

```
personList.setCellFactory(new PersonListCellFactory());
```

*WORKS*:

```
personList.setCellFactory(new PersonListCellFactory(){});
```

Can anyone reproduce this issue?

In the case of the factory the `textProperty` binding is implemented so it's not that, but anyway heres the code for the `PersonListCellFactory`:

```
package nestedcontrollerexample;

import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.scene.control.ListCell;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.util.Callback;

public class PersonListCellFactory implements Callback<ListView<Person>, ListCell<Person>> {
    @Override
    public ListCell<Person> call(ListView<Person> param) {
        return new ListCell<Person>() {
            @Override
            public void updateItem(Person person, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(person, empty);
                textProperty().unbind();
                if (person != null) {
                    textProperty().bind(Bindings.format("%s %s", person.firstNameProperty(), person.lastNameProperty()));
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

So how is this possible?

Comment: I don't think it will be possible to answer #3 without the implementation of `MyItemListCellFactory`. My guess is you have a `ListCell` implementation that doesn't update it's `item` property (as is done when calling `super.updateItem()` in your example), so the list view doesn't know about the item (it polls the selected `ListCell` for it's `item` property).

Comment: In [my example](https://github.com/james-d/Nested-Controller-Example), the binding between the editor controller and the selected item still persists if you remove the cell factory. The problem is that the list cell has no means to know to update the cell when you change the text in the text fields. (The properties in the item in the list change, but the list itself hasn't changed.) You could use an [extractor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29462624/) to get the list view to update. Note that, even without an extractor, if you do `System.out.println(personList.getItems())` it works.

Comment: I tested replacing the lambda with stand-alone classes and that seemed to work fine.

Comment: this is strange..:
anonymous class works
personList.setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<Person>, ListCell<Person>>() {
            @Override
            public ListCell<Person> call(ListView<Person> listView) {
                return new ListCell<>();
            }
        });
still works but if i replace it with lambda:
        personList.setCellFactory(listView -> new ListCell<>());
does not work WTF?!

Comment: First one does not work; all the cells are blank. Maybe your project somehow didn't rebuild?

Comment: i know the cells are blank there, i did that on purpose because, the editor binding still works, but somehow if i replace it with lambda the editor textfields are not updated when i select those 'blank' cells

Comment: The editor binding works fine for me with either the lambda or the inner class returning a blank cell.

Comment: personList.setCellFactory(param -> new ListCell<Person>()); does not work, however it does when adding the '{}' (which requires the explicit type parameter) 

personList.setCellFactory(param -> new ListCell<Person>(){}); now thats.. interesting

Comment: Both do exactly the same for me (which is not surprising; the first creates a `ListCell`, then second a subclass of `ListCell` which does nothing different to the default implementation). In both cases, the binding works as expected. I really suspect you are somehow not building the project completely every time, or some other confounding thing is happening.

Comment: thanks for all your feedback james-d, i've edited my question because it really stops working for me as soon as i remove the {} which does not makes sense to me as i would also expect thesame!
i'm using IntelliJ btw and it does build properly because i can toggle the {} and see the result in each built... so i think it just has to do with java itself

Comment: It has nothing to do with the type parameter - those are not even retained at runtime. Add a listener to the list's selected item and see if it's changing.

Comment: I figured it also has nothing to do with the implementation of updateItem and binding to the textproperty.
I've updated the post to include an listcellfactory implementing the callback but this does not change the problem. However it indicates that the problem occurs when leaving out the anonymous-inner-class brackets, and not with overriding the updateItem which as was done in the anonymous-inner-class hence it was working.
So basically I cant get it working without the curly brackets:{}!
Which is pretty strange but interesting in my opinion...

Comment: I am pretty certain this is just an issue with your IDE not properly rebuilding your project in certain circumstances. The anonymous class requires writing a class file; just creating a new `ListCell()` does not. As I said, I cannot recreate the behavior you describe. I don't use IntelliJ, so I don't know the exact mechanism to do a full clean on the project and rebuild from scratch, but it should be pretty easy to do that. Clean and rebuild the project; I suspect that will make it behave the way you would expect.

Answer (score 0):

The cell factory you provided establishes a *binding* between the `nameProperty` of the current item displayed by the cell and the cell's text. This means that when the name of the item changes, the cell is notified and updates its text.

Without this binding, even though the text fields in your editor are still bound to the properties in the item, the cell won't know to update if the properties change. So, in short, the binding between your editor and your list item still works, but there is no notification from the list item to the cell displaying the text.

If you add a button to the UI with an action handler that does

```
myItemList.getItems().forEach(System.out::println);
```

you will see that changing the text in the text field does update the underlying model, it's just that the cells have not been updated.

You can fix this by using a list with an extractor: see also [Java ListChangeListener WasUpdated() doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29462624/). This enables the list to fire update notifications (which are seen by the list view, so it updates the relevant cells) when certain properties of your model class change. In your case you would need

```
public void initialize() {
    myItemList.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(item -> 
        new Observable[]{item.nameProperty()}));
    myItemList.getItems().addAll(sampleMyItems());

    myItemEditorController.myItemProperty().bind(myItemList.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty());
}
```

Comment: i've tried your initialize method also applied to your example but the editor doesnt get notified